# Windows 8.1: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mveftps.exe neither removable nor can it be stopped

Tags: windows-8.1

EDIT: I apologise for not making that clear enough in this question. I knew about the McAfee removal tool and I don't want it.

EDIT, c'ed: I want to be able to troubleshoot exactly this situation: I ask the OS about a file and it says it's being used in that it is being executed and it gives me the PID of the process that executes the file. I send a terminating signal to said process (with force and admin rights) and get the answer that this is not possible because the process I want to kill has no running instances, which is contradictory to what I initially got from the OS.

EDIT further continued: obviously the answer to that question that I don't want to hear "well it is just like that, they protect their files". If you are about to give me that answer, don't. I'll accept it though if I hear "no troubleshooting possible because we'd need to know what your executable does".

===============
I'm on a factory reset so this likely is not malware but a remain of McAfee.

After having done a factory reset, I uninstalled every McAfee app I could find, yet still I see a "McAfee process validation service" task running. I think the only executed file is the one in the title. I want to remove that file from the disk.

I tried deleting it which results in an error due to it being used by said task. Then I tried to end the task and then remove it by running `runas /user:pc\Administrator taskkill /F /IM mfevtps.exe` which should work but responds by saying that it's not possible to kill the task because no running instance of it is found. (It also gives me the PID of the process which it claims to not have a running instance...  hawhaw)

Comment: Have you tried to use the [McAfee tool](https://service.mcafee.com/webcenter/portal/oracle/webcenter/page/scopedMD/s55728c97_466d_4ddb_952d_05484ea932c6/Page29.jspx?wc.contextURL=%2Fspaces%2Fcp&articleId=TS101331&_afrLoop=1203381205226250&leftWidth=0%25&showFooter=false&showHeader=false&rightWidth=0%25&centerWidth=100%25#!%40%40%3FshowFooter%3Dfalse%26_afrLoop%3D1203381205226250%26articleId%3DTS101331%26leftWidth%3D0%2525%26showHeader%3Dfalse%26wc.contextURL%3D%252Fspaces%252Fcp%26rightWidth%3D0%2525%26centerWidth%3D100%2525%26_adf.ctrl-state%3D8zwby94no_9) that uninstalls McAfee products?

Comment: Not yet. Main question isn't answered by that: How do you remove such an executable on windows? How do you troubleshoot the peculiarity that a process with a valid ID says that it isn't running?

Comment: McAfee products protect their executables and the methods for removing them IS to use the designed tool suggested by @ramhound.

Comment: @music2myear well, that already was clear. I want to understand what is going on. If there were a process that behaved similarly I would like to know how to get rid of it instead of relying on a program, that I might not have at this point. In hindsight I have to admit the question is formulated as if the main goal was to just get any method to remove it, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: The methods McAfee uses are very similar to those used by malware, to be frank. But they are highly technical, generally speaking, and not the sort of thing we can explain in depth here. If you want to know how McAfee protects their executables, the best thing to do is to ask McAfee. However, because these tricks make it hard for malware to close the McAfee products and bexsuee McAfee is under no rule to tell you how, I doubt you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

McAfee products protect their running executables in particularly effective ways.

The correct method of removing McAfee software when the uninstaller doesn't work is to use the [McAfee Removal Tool](https://service.mcafee.com/webcenter/portal/cp/home/articleview?articleId=TS101331).

Comment: This is not the correct way as in "it is the way that works for every executable that behaves that way". Obviously, as this tool is just for removing specific executables. Instead it is the official workaround. I want a hint on how to find out want causes the process to not be stoppable, even though I have the rights to stop it. (I mean obviously I will use the tool instead in the end, but I hoped for something more general)

Comment: This was the answer to the question that was asked. When asking questions it is important to be clear about the full goal. We will only answer the question that is asked, and so if what you post isn't the actual question, you'll get what happened here: you waste our time and effort and end up with answers you don't want.

Comment: I see that now and I apologise, maybe I should just repost and ask more elaborate. Thank you for giving me a working answer.